# Are there any cases in which: $x \neq (x)$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, notation, arithmetic

My question: is this true?
$x\over y$= $(x) \over y$

Comment: What's $(x){}$?

Comment: Its not a specific case. Any variable.

Comment: $x\in\mathbb{R}$

Comment: Your comments on your previous section seem to show that this is a question about entering calculations into a calculator. If that is the case you need to explain much more in your question, because as it stands the question does not give the detail or context to enable people to understand what you are asking. Algebraically the two expressions are trivially the same.

Comment: Yes but if its the same algebraicly then its also always the same in the calculator. So I thought I can adress my problem at the root which should overule the handling of the calculator (hierarchicaly if its algebraic correct the calculator will also work correct) , plus improve my basic mathematic understanding, plus eleminate uncertainty.

Comment: Thank you though for pointing that out and thus helping me on my learning ark for stack exchange. If I need to ask a question now I think I might be able to check if it is specific and clear. Thank you :)

Comment: Yes! I have concluded now that there is never any difference and i can use parenthesis in the way I intended without issues.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You asked this question a day ago [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4859531/fractions-is-the-result-always-equal-or-can-there-be-a-difference-numerator-de).

As people pointed out there, parentheses do not change the value, $(x)$ is equal to $x$. Unless you mean something else by parentheses, the posted equation is always true.

Comment: Thank you alot! This is a relief!

Comment: I realized I did not express myself in my first question very good. Therefore i revisited and started to learn how to use LaTeX for better clarity.

Comment: I hope I am not annoying anyone. I can delete my questions if you suggest.

Comment: No problem. The effort to format in LaTeX is appreciated! I guess I'm just a little confused.. Were the answers given there not sufficient? Generally you only ask a question once.

Comment: A bot recommended me to edit my question. I was unsure because i realized how unclear it was how to continue. I realized that my question at its core is as posted here much better understandable . But if I would edit my old question maybe the comments to it would not make any sense anymore. I will probably keep it as a reminder to where I started to remind my self to think if i can improve my questions.